# "The installed version of Xcode (3.1.4) is too old" error in port after installing Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, macports

A have freshly checked-out from svn, built and installed MacPorts. I have installed Xcode4.3. I get the following error when trying to call "sudo port install X":

Error: The installed version of Xcode (3.1.4) is too old to use on the installed OS version. Version 4.1 or later is recommended on Mac OS X 10.7.

"xcodebuild -version" returns:

XcodeComponent versions: DevToolsCore-1809.0; DevToolsSupport-1806.0
BuildVersion: 10M2518

I have recently updated MacOS to Lion and I used to have an older version of xCode in SnowLeopard, which didn't work in the new system. I didn't uninstall it explicitly, but I also don't find any trace of the old Xcode on my system.

Any ideas? Please, help!

Answer (score 10):

Xcode 4.3 should prompt you to remove any older versions when you run it for the first time, but check to make sure you don't have a `/Developer` directory anyway.

Have you run `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`?  What does `xcode-select -print-path` tell you?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem as the OP and found this thread in a search.  Installing Xcode 4.3 today didn't prompt for removal of older version (at least that I recall seeing), and /Developer hierarchy is still present.   Renaming to /Developer.ex solved MacPort's problem.   Can I safely delete /Developer completely?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the /Developer helped (although Xcode-select -print-path returns "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer").